# Unexpected bracket when using "if" inside function

Tags: r, function

I constructed the function, but the R gives me the error. But I does not know what I did wrongly.

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Vect_fun=function(x,a) {
      if(a=1)
      {
       y= mean(x,na.rm=TRUE) 
      }
      else{
        if(a=2)
        {
         y= na.aggregate(x)
        }
        else {
          y=x[!is.na(x)]
        }
      }
      y
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double equal sign to comparing.

```
Vect_fun = function(x, a) {
  if (a == 1) {
    y = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  else {
    if (a == 2) {
      y = na.aggregate(x)
    }
    else {
      y = x[!is.na(x)]
    }
  }
  y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is off in addition to needing to use the proper `==` operator, and `else if`

You should indent at each level so it's easier to read, and you need to use `==` for logical operators. Also, `else{ if(){ }}` is messy. Use `else if{  }`

```
Vect_fun <- function(x,a) {
  if (a == 1) {

    y = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) 

    } else if (a == 2) {

      y = na.aggregate(x)

      return(y)
      } else { 

        y = x[!is.na(x)] 
      }

  return(y)
}
```